# Scale down an image to a fixed width and Height with same aspect resolution

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to scale down an uploaded image to a fixed with and height for example: **width=200px and height 200px**. I tried to scale down the width of the image with a fixed width and calculate the new height by its new width. What now i am trying to achieve is to scale down both width and height to a fixed size **width=200px & height =200px**

My HTML:

```
        <form action="do_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload_image">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

do_upload.php:

```
<?php

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_image"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["upload_image"]["name"]);

$image_path = "uploads/" . $_FILES["upload_image"]["name"];

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_path);

$newwidth = 200;
$newheight = ($height / $width) * $newwidth;

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($tmp, "uploads/small.jpeg", 100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp); 
?>
```

This is working fine for me and scaling down the image. Kindly guide me how can i scale down all image (jpeg,png,gif etc) to a fixed width and height. Just guide me in the direction i will do it. If anyone can explain with an example or edit my code for me it will be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use a third party library such as https://github.com/search?l=PHP&o=desc&q=image+manipulation&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @martinezdelariva i want it to done in PHP.

Comment: When you say "fixed size" do you mean fixed MAXIMUM size.  You do mention aspect ratio in the title bu not in your post, so it is not clear if you want to scale proportionately.  Assuming you do, the next question is what happens with non-square images.  You obviously need to scale width to 200 for a landscape image and height to 200 for a portrait image. The question is, is it OK to have the other dimension be less than 200px, or are you looking to add (perhaps transparent) pixels to the image to make sure it is exactly 200 x 200 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

You can see comment above to answer question about what to do with dimension that is less than 200 and aspect ration.  That being said, I can go ahead and answer the question on how to scale on either dimension.  Basically the problem is pretty simple.

First you determine if existing image has width or height which is greater dimension.  Based on that, you determine the scaling factor for the image and then apply that scaling factor to both dimensions.

In code that might look like:

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_path);

$max_dimension = 200;
if($width >= $height) {
    // scale on width
    $scaling_factor = $width / $max_dimension;
} else {
    // scale on height
    $scaling_factor = $height / $max_dimension;
}

$new_width = $width / $scaling_factor;
$new_height = $height / $scaling_factor;
```

A more generalized solution which would let you specify any rectangle (i.e. different max height and width) within which to scale might look like this.

```
$max_width = 200;
$max_height = 150;
// determine which dimension must be scaled to fit target size
$width_scaling_factor = $width / $max_width;
$height_scaling_factor = $height / $max_height;
if($width_scaling_factor >= $height_scaling_factor) {
    $scaling_factor = $width_scaling_factor;
} else {
    $scaling_factor = $height_scaling factor;
}

$new_width = $width / $scaling_factor;
$new_height = $height / $scaling_factor;
```

Comment: let me explain what i am trying to achieve. I have a div having size height=200px and width=200px. i want to display an image in it from the form. i want the image to be fit in the div without losing aspect ration and become 200px x 200px

Comment: @Raja So what if the image is say 400 x 300?  This would scale down to 200 X 150 if aspect ratio is fixed. Do you want a 200 X 150 image or do you want a 200 x 200 image which is really the 200 x 150 image with 50 pixels worth of added vertical padding (perhaps with transparent pixels, white pixels, etc.)?